# Ember.js nested routes with shared models

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I have this on my router.js:

```
this.resource('campaigns', {path:'/campaigns'}, function() {
  this.route('index', {path: '/'});
  this.route('group', {path: '/*campaign_group_id'});
});
```

So it's a route called *campaigns*, and 2 nested routes: *index* and *group*.

When the browser is on the *group* route, I need to access the model from group route, on the campaigns route/controller.

But I can't access it. I always get the model that it's on campaigns.js route.

Comment: what are you trying to do with the model? Separation of concerns is somewhat violated if you try to let the parent route/controller know what the child controller is trying to do.

Comment: I am just trying to access a property of the child model's promise to use on that campaigns parent route.

Comment: Why don't you use campaigns route model to retrieve what you need?

Comment: No, I can't, otherwise the model on campaigns, doesn't have access to the params of the route campaigns/group. And I need those params to make the proper call to the API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the model from the `campaign.group` route on its controller, you should be able to use [`controllerFor`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_controllerFor) to from the `campaigns` route, something like

```
// routes/campaigns.js
this.controllerFor('campaigns.group').get('your-prop')
```

You could also send an action from your `group` route and handle it in the parent `campaigns` route, sending along the model. This is perhaps more idiomatic with Ember 2.0 conventions.

Btw if you're using Ember CLI (which you should be) you should try getting rid of `this.resource` and putting all your routes/templates/controllers in pods.